# How I can modify the error message in a flutter firebase-ui screen?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the official firebase-ui example from here:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example

When my cloud functions return an error, the error is shown in the UI explicitly:
[image: Error message]

Instead, I want to modify the message to be more user friendly based on the error that I get. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to do that. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There's now a way to customize any error message.

API docs:

- [`ErrorText.localizeError`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ui_auth/latest/firebase_ui_auth/ErrorText/localizeError.html)
- [`ErrorText.localizePlatformError`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ui_auth/latest/firebase_ui_auth/ErrorText/localizePlatformError.html)

Example:

```dart
ErrorText.localizeError = (BuildContext context, FirebaseAuthException e) {
  // I'm assuming this should be the code, but it might be different
  if (e.code == -47) return 'Custom message goes here';
  
  final defaultLabels = FirebaseUILocalizations.labelsOf(context);
  return localizedErrorText(e.code, defaultLabels);
}
```

Comment: I solved it by putting ErrorText inside the actions

actions: [
      AuthStateChangeAction<AuthFailed>((context, state) {
       <code here>
        }),
]